# access button click event from another .aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have two .aspx pages. The first opens the second page. On the second page is a button. 
How can I access the button click event from the first page?

The second page is loaded from an included javascript file:

```
someReturnValue = openDialog("test.aspx");
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Also, what is "opens the second page"?

Comment: I want then if the button on the second page is clicked, call a js function that is declared on the first page.

Comment: Not 'per se'. This is not a Winform app. 
Maybe you can open 2nd form on a iframe using jquery, etc....

Comment: Second page - is it in new window? Or is it in the same? And yes - show your code. How function is defined, how second page is opened etc.

Comment: how do you load the second page? using iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the target control ClientID (?TargetID={ClientID}) to the child window, the following code should fire the click event:

```
public void Save()
{
string TargetID = this.Page.Request.QueryString.Item("TargetID");
if (TargetID.Length > 0) {
    string scriptContent = "window.opener.document.getElementById('" + TargetID + "').click();window.close();";
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "SelectValueScript", scriptContent, true);
}
}
```